# Is the calculation of the series in this video correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOHrNt9ScYs) (from MIT OCW) and Prof. Jerison is explaining about series. He is trying to calculate that if some blocks of equal length are kept on top of each other, will the last block be able to cross the first one or not.

[image: image of blocks]

He has calculated the series and found it is:

$$C_n=1+1/2+1/3+1/4+\ldots1/n$$

[image: blackboard image]

Using this, he showed that he can take the blocks as far as he wants. But according to me, the correct series should be $$C_n=1+1/2+1/4+1/8+\ldots+1/2^n$$ and the series converges to $2$, so he cannot take the blocks farther than the edge of the first block.

So am I right? If I am right, please also tell where was the mistake in the video?

Comment: I didn't watch the video but he is right about the series and this fact is totally awesome :)

Comment: @Einer Can you explain why he is right? Many people have commented on the video saying that he is wrong.

Comment: @Kartik, are you unsure about the expression $C_{N+1}=C_N+\frac{1}{N+1}$? Or do you understand that much?

Comment: To be honest, I really don't want to redo the calculation right now or watch the video given its length. Most likely, I would just redo what is shown in the video. Maybe, someone else will provide you with a solution or trustworthy reference.

Comment: @BeaumontTaz I cannot properly undertand that from where did he get it. But when he said that the center of mass of Every block will be half  ahead of the previous one, then it became clear that the series should be 1+1/2+1/4+1/8....

Comment: @Kartik, each block will be half ahead of the previous *center of mass* of *all* the previous blocks. Not just the last block. I'm typing out an explanation for this that uses both words and the symbols he uses that might help some.

Comment: @Kartik, do you understand how $C_{N+1}=C_N+\frac{1}{N+1}$ turns into $C_N=1+1/2+1/3+1/4+\ldots+1/N$?

Comment: @BeaumontTaz Yes I can understand the formulas but not the reasoning behind the main formula.

Comment: If you have a deck of 52 cards, it's really not very difficult at all to get the top card well past the edge of the deck. In theory you can get it 2.26 card lengths past the edge, but that's much more difficult and requires great precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When he writes that the next block, the $N+1$<sup>th</sup> block, has a center that is 1 more than the *center of mass* of all the of the blocks before it, $C_N$. We're not saying that the next center of mass if $1$ more to the right, we're saying that we're placing the next block $1$ to the right of the previous center of mass.

And *now* we want to come up with the expression for $C_{N+1}$, the *new* center of mass after adding the next block. The center of mass of objects is a weighted average, therefore, we sum the products of mass and position for each block. But we can group the first $N$ blocks into one "block" with a mass of $N$ (we assume that each block has a mass of $1$ to make things simple).

So our new center of mass, $C_{N+1}$, is the mass of the old blocks, $N$, multiplied by the old center of mass, $C_N$, added to the mass of the new block, $1$, multiplied by the new location which we established as being $1$ more to the right of the old center of mass, $C_N+1$ (Note the 1 is not in the subscript), all divided by the total mass of the new system, $N+1$.

This yields the equation:

$$C_{N+1}=\frac{NC_N+C_N+1}{N+1}$$

Algebraic manipulation can transform that into the relation he ended with:

$$C_{N+1}=C_N+\frac{1}{N+1}$$

Comment: Now I understood it. Thanks.